# How to modify item shape of specific group when using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uibezierpath, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am making a collage app for that I will be using multiple grid layouts.I am using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to create grids. One of my grids requires a heart shaped cell in between. Following is my code the HeartShaped item needs to be heartShape I've no idea how to do it at first I thought of using UIBeizerPath but item is not type of layer and if somehow I manage to do it inside cellForItem still I've many more grids coming and I will have to use "if" "else" again and again. Another problem I am facing my last group i.e the bottom group is not displaying.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
                let topItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
                
//                top items group
                let topGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/4)), subitem: topItem, count: 3)
                topGroup.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 3, bottom: 0, trailing: 3)
                topGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(2)

//                middle right item
                let middleRightItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))

//                 middle left item
                let middleLeftItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))

//                Heart Shaped
                let heartShapedItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/2), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))

//                 middle three items group
                let middleGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/3)), subitems: [middleRightItem,heartShapedItem,middleLeftItem])
                middleGroup.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 3, bottom: 0, trailing: 3)
                middleGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(2)

//            bottom three items group
                let bottomGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/4)), subitem: topItem, count: 3)
                
                let finalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)), subitems: [topGroup,middleGroup,bottomGroup])
                finalGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(2)
                
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: finalGroup)
                
                return section
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A collection view layout defines the visual arrangement of the content in your collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/layouts) - thus in your `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` you specify such parameters of your collection view like number of items in a row, sizes and offsets, orthogonal scrolling behavior, headers and decoration items, not how a particular cell looks like.

In `cellForItem` you could customize your cells including its layers - you could modify shapes there. Cells will be arranged in the collection view based on parameters of your `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

If you are using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, you could differentiate between different type of cells (i.e. cells with a heart shape and a circle shape) with a following code example:

```
func configureDataSource() {
    dataSource = DataSource(collectionView: collectionView) { [self] (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: ViewCell) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
        switch item.type {
        case .heart:  return hearCell(for: indexPath)
        case .circle: return circleCell(for: indexPath)
        default:      return normalCell(for: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

In custom struct ViewCell I have an enum for CellType:

```
struct ViewCell: Hashable {
    var tag: Int
    var type: CellType
}

enum CellType { case heart, circle }
```

Regarding the problem with the bottom group - do you have enough items in your collection view to fill all the groups?

**UPDATE:**

The problem in your layout is with this line:

```
middleGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(2)
```

With it 3 rows in the middle group can't be placed in one row. You could remove it and achieve the same spacing by adding insets to the middle item:

```
heartShapedItem.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 2, bottom: 0, trailing: 2)
```

Since you are not using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, you could differentiate your cells by indexPath. So if you have just 1 section, your heartShape item will have indexPath.row of 4:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.label.textAlignment = .center
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    
    if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0) {
        cell.label.text = "HEART"
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

[image]

(in your original code there is not spacing between items in the bottom group, I don't know if it was done intentionally or not)

Comment: yes I do have all enough items I am using topitem twice

Comment: can you tell me how can I use enum with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout sorry I am not very good with swift yet if you want I can share my code for flowlayout

Comment: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout could be used either with UICollectionViewDataSource (which you are using) or UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource (which I suggest to use). Enum I've shown in my answer is part of UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource and allows to differentiate cells not only by indexPath (like in your case with collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)), but with custom item too. Custom item could have as many properties as you need, including enum for the cell type.

Comment: dataSource =  UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section,imageModel>(collectionView: collectionView!) { [self] (CollectionView, indexPath, image) -> CollectionViewCell  This is my diffabledatasource I am really confused on how to use the enum sorry for bothering but I am not much experienced with swift. I loved the way diffable works I changed my code to diffable now but still not sure how to access the item using enum.

Comment: You should add a property "type" to your imageModel (I've updated the code with an example for it). After that you could use a switch statement in your dataSource to differentiate between image types as shown in my answer

Comment: I understand your point now. OK! I can't use type property inside imageModel. I have to use section enum because its a collage app now I am trying to make multiple sections inside enum but when I create switch inside UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout it throws error "Enum case 'main' is not a member of type 'UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout'"

Comment: If you can't change imageModel, you could create a struct which will have a property for the imageModel, as well as enum for cell type. I am not sure I understand what are you trying to do with enum in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

Comment: With DiffableDataSource you are creating a snapshot which has sections and items, related to this sections. I suggest that your items should have a type property so you could create different cells (i.e. heart shape). In your UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout you specify visual arrangement of the cells in the section - like how many items do you want in group, which insets, etc. You could have an enum for CompositionalLayout too, but it will differentiate between sections, not items.

Comment: First i need to differentiate between thee section each section is a collage user can choose one at time depending on the chosen collage grid will be displayed. I already created multiple layouts so now I want to display different layout for each section. If i assign a type property with image I am not sure which collagee user going to pick.

Comment: Thank you very much Viktor it wasn't exactly what I wanted to do but you bought me really close to what I wanted to do and I did it with your help